# Is there any options in Vivo V5 that in silent mode vibration can also be stop?

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, vivo

I have Vivo V5 Android device with Funtouch OS provided by Vivo company.

In this device, when I switch profile mode from General to Silent. It cannot turn off vibration.
I want to turn off vibration also.

Please update with solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Go to **Settings** -> **Sounds**

Here, turn off the vibrate toggle switch. Hope this helps.

Comment: For this, I always have to go to Sound menu and turn off vibration?

Comment: No, just once,just like any other settings. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Please see https://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing